# How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL and perform GROUP BY a 'column'

Tags: mysql, group-by, outer-join

Here are my DMLs and DLLs:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `value1` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `value2` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `table3` (
  `id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `value3` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `table4` (
  `id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `value4` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `table1`
(`id`, `email`, `value1`)
VALUES
(1, 'email1@test.com', 1.1),
(2, 'email2@test.com', 1.2);

INSERT INTO `table2`
(`id`, `email`, `value2`)
VALUES
(2, 'email2@test.com', 2.2);

INSERT INTO `table3`
(`id`, `email`, `value3`)
VALUES
(1, 'email1@test.com', 3.1),
(2, 'email2@test.com', 3.2);

INSERT INTO `table4`
(`id`, `email`, `value4`)
VALUES
(1, 'email1@test.com', 4.1),
(2, 'email2@test.com', 4.2);
```

This is what I am currently doing to emulate FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
LEFT JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t3.id = t4.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table1 as t1 
RIGHT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
LEFT JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t3.id = t4.id
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table1 as t1 
RIGHT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
RIGHT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
LEFT JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t3.id = t4.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table1 as t1 
RIGHT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
RIGHT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
RIGHT JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t3.id = t4.id
WHERE t3.id IS NULL;
```

The result is like:

| id | email | value1 | id | email | value2 | id | email | value3 | id | email | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email1@test.com | 1.1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | email2@test.com | 1.2 | 2 | email2@test.com | 2.2 | 2 | email2@test.com | 3.2 | 2 | email2@test.com | 4.2 |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 | email1@test.com | 3.1 | 1 | email1@test.com | 4.1 |

Desired result:

| id | email | value1 | id | email | value2 | id | email | value3 | id | email | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email1@test.com | 1.1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 | email1@test.com | 3.1 | 1 | email1@test.com | 4.1 |
| 2 | email2@test.com | 1.2 | 2 | email2@test.com | 2.2 | 2 | email2@test.com | 3.2 | 2 | email2@test.com | 4.2 |

My questions:

1. As you can see from the result, id = 1 gets split into 2 rows. Why? How can I get all ids to be in a single row with their respective values. Basically have all row be of unique ids and email. If they have values in each table then show it else show NULL.
2. I would like to not have the id and email repeat and have it only once at the beginning. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Try searching for mysql full join..

Comment: Not sure why my markup tables in my post isn't showing up as tables, it shows up when I preview it as well and try to edit it but doesn't show up in the post. Sorry about that. Don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @NikhilJohny Just add one more line break between headline and the table markup.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.*,
       table2.*,
       table3.*,
       table4.*
FROM (
  SELECT id FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id FROM table2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id FROM table3
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM table4  
  ) AS table0
LEFT JOIN table1 USING (id)
LEFT JOIN table2 USING (id)
LEFT JOIN table3 USING (id)
LEFT JOIN table4 USING (id)
```

| id | email | value1 | id | email | value2 | id | email | value3 | id | email | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email1@test.com | 1.1 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1 | email1@test.com | 3.1 | 1 | email1@test.com | 4.1 |
| 2 | email2@test.com | 1.2 | 2 | email2@test.com | 2.2 | 2 | email2@test.com | 3.2 | 2 | email2@test.com | 4.2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6zv6HUvD)